# Remove "ad-type.google.com" adware in any Android device browser

Tags: browser, chrome-for-android, malware

`ad-type.google.com` is appearing regularly whenever I access the web through Chrome. It's a new adware and there are no solutions available other than

> Go to system Settings > Applications > Chrome > Clear cache

But this seems to be not working. After few minutes, it appears again in few devices, we can't uninstall the browser in Nexus devices. Factory reset also doesn't work according to few of them who tried

Related link on [Google product forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/Q74jiLWfLdM%5B176-200%5D).

Comment: Based on [a thread on Android Central forum](http://forums.androidcentral.com/general-help-how/564717-most-stubborn-malware-adware-total-ad-performance-ad-type-google.html), disable JavaScript for temporary solution. Also, it might the case that not only your device, but your router is affected too. Will research more about it.

Comment: Also, some info on [Avast forum](https://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=174875.30)... probably changing DNS might help.

Answer (score 7):

`ad-type.google.com` **redirect** adware has been most stubborn malware on the internet now.

**Step 1:** [Disable](http://www.wikihow.com/Enable-JavaScript-on-an-Android-Phone) **JavaScript** in all your browsers

**Step 2:** Install [Malwarebytes **Anti-malware**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.malwarebytes.antimalware) for android

This should inhibit the infection.
If Problem persists go ahead with next step

**Step 3:** Your router might be infected too.
 Ask your ISP(internet service provider) to [change your DNS](https://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=174875.msg1244242#msg1244242) server settings.

Also see protect your [phone from infecting](http://www.quora.com/How-do-I-get-rid-of-an-Ad-type-google-com-virus-from-my-Android-phone)

Comment: changing DNS server settings possible with 3g/4g/3g ?

Comment: @LOG_TAG you have redirecting virus when using wifi or mobiledata?

Comment: @LOG_TAG you can change DNS settings in 3G/4G using [OverrideDns](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.mx17.overridedns) app. _Your device should be rooted though._

Comment: while using mobiledata it's redirecting

Comment: @LOG_TAG there;'s no solution for mobile data yet, as for WiFi you can use   OverrideDns app but needs root access

Comment: Thanks for the info, what I did is downgraded to kitkat and upgraded to Nexus 5 android M image, now it's working fine.  I'm not sure it's a right solution

Comment: Malwarebytes Anti-malware helps me saving a lot of time. I've tried to reset my ASUS Z010D several times but it is still infected with ads. After scanning with this tool, the AsusNetwork.apk has been discovered that it has a high risky.

Answer (score 2):

There is host file in /system/etc/ Folder. You need ROOT access.

1. Just go to host file using root browser.
2. Open it with text editor.
3. Write following code : ad-type.google.com 74.125.224.72

You will now go to google.com PAGE.

Comment: while using wifi it's loading fine!! when I switch from wifi to 3g adware popups redirects , any reason?

Comment: I can't root my device, any chance wait for google chrome update will work??

Comment: Currently this is the solution i know. If you solve it let us know!

Answer (score 2):

[Adbock](https://adblockplus.org/en/android-about) for non-rooted devices
[Adfree](http://adfree.odiousapps.com/) for rooted devices

The two above adblockers should help you block the ads, but they can't fix the problem for you. You'll need to root your phone and follow the answer from Saif-RX that is at the top of the page.

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same issue for the past one week. Have tried the below

- Installed AV and ran scan. nothing helped. [Didnt Help]
- Cleared Chrome cache [Didnt Help]
- Disabled Javascript. it worked but few contents were missing in the webpages. [Partially worked]

Was about to factory reset the phone but did one last thing which helped.

Settings-> Storage -> Cached Data. Cleared this and the problem is resolved.

Try this. This should work. Worked for me :)..
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This website is responsible for the browser redirection (http://www.onclickads.net/)
You need to block it in order to stop the malware that redirects your browser

I blocked it in my home router and since then when i am on that wifi, i get no redirections

Answer (score 0):

If you are using UC browset go to
Browser setting-----> clear records ----> clear all record
It will definately help.